# How do I locate/obtain the CoreMedia.framework and begin working with it?

Tags: iphone, ios, frameworks, cordova, ios-frameworks

I tried googling it but it's hard to find it. Is there any way to download the CoreMedia framework to include in my app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your Xcode project, there will be several frameworks (in the "Frameworks" folder). If you right click any of these and then click "Show in Finder" you can have a complete list of all the frameworks, ready to drag and drop into your project. CoreMedia.framework is one of these. This applies to all versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

It's included with XCode, just add a new framework under the "link to other libraries" build phase.

Answer (score 1):

This is included with the iOS SDK. You can link against the Core Media framework in Xcode.  The reason why you don't find it anywhere is because it doesn't come separately.

Answer (score 0):

It's already there if you have installed the iOS SDK. You need to add the framework to your project. Which version of Xcode are you using?